# How can I find questions with 0 or 1 answer?

Tags: support, search

I want to find all questions that have only 1 or no answer. I tried to search with `answers:1`, but this does exactly the opposite. It shows all questions with a minimum of 1 answer, but I want to have all questions with a maximum of 1 answer. How is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

The [Questions->unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered) does exactly what you're looking for. It does not show questions with no answers, but *unanswered* questions, that is questions with no accepted answers.

[image]

Comment: 2 freehand circles are not always better than 1. This is only true for girls.

Comment: @Roflcoptr, well, just for you...

Comment: @MByD: You sure have a steady hand!

Comment: It is a very good approach but it does not exactly what I want. I want to find question with 0 or 1 answer, independent if it has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there's a way to do that with the site's search utilities. If you're OK with slightly old data, try [this Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2273/questions-with-a-maximum-of-1-answer).

Comment: Thanks. But I forgot to mention that I need that for a beta site.